# return the sorted array React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can return the sorted array from method.
Here is the code i need to display the sorted array as list.it doent work when i return  numbers from sortList().Why? Return numbers is not returning the array in JSX. Is not the correct place to use return statement.

```
function RenderList(props){
 let numbers=props.number;
 function sortList(){
    numbers.sort();
    return numbers
 }
 const numList=numbers.map((num)=>(
    <li>{num}</li>
 ))
 return(
   <div>
    <h2>Rendering List</h2>
    <button onClick={sortList}>SortList</button>
    <ul>{numList}</ul>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: You need to make a `setState()` in order to re-render the component.

Comment: Is not possible to sort list using functional component..i dont want to use state here

Comment: @kalhan can you provide an example

Comment: You can use the useState hook to introduce state to your functional component: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qqyt6t

Answer (score 0):

You need to store numbers array in a state, and then update the state to re-render.

```
function RenderList(props){
 const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState(props.numbers);
 function sortList(){
    setNumbers(numbers.slice().sort());
 }
 const numList=numbers.map((num)=>(
    <li>{num}</li>
 ))
 return(
   <div>
    <h2>Rendering List</h2>
    <button onClick={sortList}>SortList</button>
    <ul>{numList}</ul>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: is it possible to sort the array without using state

Comment: It is possible, but it is an antipattern in ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

If you really dont want to use `useState` then you can do something like this

```
const [sort, setSort] = useState(false);

<button onClick={triggerSort}>SortList</button>

const triggerSort = () => {
    if (!sort) {//if you remove this check and keep only setSort(!sort) then you can get sorted and non-sorted list when clicking
        setSort(!sort)
    }        
}

const numList= (sort ? [...numbers].sort() : numbers).map((num)=>(
    <li>{num}</li>
))
```

here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2f2deh?file=index.js)

---

and if you think the sorting is some complex thing to do in each render, use the `useMemo`, so sorting will call only when `sort` gets change.

```
const numbersList = useMemo(() => {
    return sort ? [...numbers].sort() : numbers
}, [sort]);
.....
<ul>
   {
      numbersList.map(num => <li>{num}</li>)
   }
</ul>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ugqjb6?file=index.js)